# What's the difference between doing cat and between piping only

Tags: bash

assume I wrote this script :

```
#print_time..
cat <file1.txt> | grep "*.log" | head -4 | tail -2 | helper | sort -r -n -k2


#helper..
while read line; do
  linearr=($line)
  (( time =${line[2]}  - ${line[1]} +0 ))
  echo ${line[o]} $time
done
```

two questions:
1) why the first script works as expected only when I write it like this:

```
cat `cat <file1.txt> | grep "*.log" | head -4 | tail -2`  helper | sort -r -n -k2
```

2) Should I use `grep "*.log"` or grep ".log" ?

What the script does:

given a file1, we want to read only 2 log files when the last one is the number 4 of all the .log files in the given file1:
example :

[image]

I want the first part of the script to read : tuesday.log and wednesday.log
and after that to calculate the time of every log time of every person whose name is in the log's files: 
[image]

and this will be printed out :

[image]

Comment: 1. Please post real code. `<file1.txt>` looks like you're writing redirections but evidently you meant that to be a file name. 2. What does the file contain?

Comment: I meant it to be written like this so you can understand that it's just a file.
and the file contains names of another files.
I need the log file only out of it

Comment: Don't engage in Useless Use of Cat. It might cost you milliseconds of additional CPU time, but what's more annoying is the people who'll be badgering your for it.

Comment: @SijaanHallak Don't make us guess. Post actual code and input.

Comment: Because in bash the characters < and > have meaning, it makes your examples confusing, if you're using <file1.txt> just as placeholder, just put a real filename, e.g. cat file1.txt . Remove the gt and lt signs.

Comment: Edited. I hopeyou understand whats my point now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the problem is with your usage of `grep`.

Grep takes what you put as a literal, so if you grep with `*.log`, it will actively look for the character star `*` followed by `.log`, so it won't find anything.

As a quick test,

The command `echo hello.log | grep "*.log"` will return nothing

The command `echo hello.log | grep ".log"` will return the line

Comment: Okay. how can I use grep so this works also `*.log` ?

Comment: Updated the answer. You would have to grep ".log" without any star. So it will only include lines where it pattern matches and sees ".log" somewhere on the line.

Comment: Thank you. And anything about my first question? Because it still works only with the second script I wrote of `print_time`

Comment: Just to situate myself could you tell me more what the end result of that script should be? What is it trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Ahh, I figured it out. It's because I want the content of these files and by piping I was only passing their names!
You put this in your answer. and thanks for your kind replies unlike others

Comment: Ok no prob good that you figured it out.

Comment: Grep uses regular expression (by default). Asterisk in BRE is only interpreted as literal `*` if it is *the first character*, *in a bracket* or *first character of a subexpression*. Else it say *repeat previous 0+times*. In ERE an asterisk at start of pattern is undefined. The dot represent any character, not only `.` so in your solution you would match ***any string having `<?>log` as part of name. E.g. "blog", "blogging", "blog.txt" etc.*** A proper match would be done by `\.log$` or `.*\.log$` (if one want to match entire line.)